# White outlines around characters from sun lighting

Tags: rendering, light, scene

So, I'm trying to make a minecraft scene and every time I put a sun in the scene it puts a white outline on the characters. [image]

Comment: Welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange!  It would be helpful if you could upload your .blend file to a site like [http://pasteall.org/blend/](http://pasteall.org/blend/) so we can look at it and find out what is causing the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the alpha representation for a texture with transparency.
Try both choices

Straight or Premultiplied

Located in the texture settings image panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having this issue a while back too. If the above answer doesn't help, try enabling or even just switching to Z-transparency in your material settings for the character (in Blender Internal). I don't understand why, but this worked for me.

[image]